# Webdriver: How to remove an elementy using js

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to remove an element using webdriver.

Unfortunately a WebDriver element doesn't have a `remove` method.

I've tried to remove an element using its parent

```
 child.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("./.."))
                .then((parent) => {
                    parent.remove(element);
                });
```

Any suggestion how I can remove `child` ? Also, is there an easier way to get the parent element ?

Comment: JavaScriptExecutor in selenium can help you execute a JavaScript. I dont know python selenium binding. But there must be execute_script command and you can send the Javascript there. For JS to remove a node see this http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately an `element` is not able to suicide. The parent will have to kill it.

You could change the `Xpath` to `child.findelement(webdriver.By.xpath(".."))` as you you're automatically calling the current element so there is no need for the `./`.

Another way you could remove your `element` is by executing a `javascript` command manually.

```
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].parentNode.removeChild(arguments[0]);", child);
```